# Creating and Adding new items to new Dictionary

Tags: c#

```
public class Employee
{
   public Dictionary<key, MyClass>  MyDictionary;
   // ....
}

MyClass cls;

if(employeeObject.MyDictionary != null && employeeObject.MyDictionary.ContainsKey(dicKey)
{
  // .... 
}
else
{
  MyClass cls = new MyClass();
  myclass.Name = "John";
  //...set some other properties on it

  employeeObject.MyDictionary.Add(dicKey, cls)
}
```

So first I check to see if my object is not null and then I create it, but even when I am creating it in the `else` section, and then I want to add it in the last line, still it says `employeeObject.MyDictionary` is `null` so it crashes on it because it is `null.Add`

So what should I do?

Comment: You need to initialize

Comment: Where are you creating your `employeeObject.MyDictionary`? Can you show that code, please?

Comment: I don't see where you are actually creating the dictionary.

Comment: @Sajeetharan please be more specific and an example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize dictionary before using it:

```
public class Employee
{
   public Dictionary<key, MyClass> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<key, MyClass>();

}
```

Otherwise class field will have default value, which is `null` for reference types. See [C# Specification 10.4.4 Field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value (Section 5.2) of the field's
>   type.

Comment: Judging from the description in the question, the OP is already fully aware of all that - cf. "I check to see if my object is not null and then I create it"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper judging from error *still it says employeeObject.MyDictionary is null so it crashes on it because it is null.Add* field has `null` value. I think OP is not aware of default field value.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper oh no, I added that "null" check later after I saw it was crashing on Null and still didn't fix it and was crashing so I posted the question to the site. So that's how I added that null check :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think his object is employeeObject, so he is probably not fully aware of that.

Comment: @mmg666: Well, he or she *is* checking `employeeObject.MyDictionary != null`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper please see where check occurs

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: At a possibly right place. In the question, the OP is aware that they need to check the dictionary for `null`, and that they need to initialize it if it is `null`. (That the combination with the other condition may create a follow-up problem here is beside the point.) The issue is that the code in the question *does not initialize the dictionary* in contradiction to the description saying so.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks, Can I just initialize my Dictionaries that I have in the class all in the constructor? then get rid of checking for null and also creating the objects in else sections?

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper: Yes. Unless you have a compelling reason to initialize them later, *always* initialize them in the constructor (or "inline", right with the declaration). To be sure that no-one accidentally ever sets them to `null`, you can then also mark your dictionary member as `readonly`.

Answer (score 1):

You have just declared your `Dictionary`, you haven't initialized it. You can do that either at the time of declaration or in constructor.

```
 public Dictionary<key, MyClass>  MyDictionary = new Dictionary<key, MyClass>();
```

Or in constructor like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Dictionary<key, MyClass> MyDictionary;
    // ....

    public Employee()
    {
        MyDictionary = new Dictionary<key, MyClass>();
    }
}
```

For your question:

> So first I check to see if my object is not null and then I create it,
>   but even when I am creating it in the else section,

You check for your dictionary being null, but you don't instantiate it in else part, instead you create an object of your `MyClass`. That will have no effect on the dictionary.

You can do:

```
else
{
  employeeObject.MyDictionary = new Dictionary<key, MyClass>();
  MyClass cls = new MyClass();
  myclass.Name = "John";
  //...set some other properties on it

  employeeObject.MyDictionary.Add(dicKey, cls)
}
```

Comment: Based on the description in the question, the OP is already aware of that and wants to create the dictionary lazily for some reason.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I added that "null" check later after I saw it was crashing on Null and still didn't fix it and was crashing so I posted the question to the site. So that's how I added that null check :) –

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, OP is not instantiating the dictionary in else part, He/She is creating an object of `MyClass`, but the dictionary is still `null`

Comment: @Habib: I see that. That's why your answer is now the better answer IMO, because it actually addresses the problem (that the dictionary is not actually initialized) rather than explain something that the OP already knows -> +1.